# JS TreeView file icon not showing PHP

Tags: php, jquery, treeview, jstree

I have created jsTree view in php, problem is that showing folder icon all li, i want file icon where file is available pls let me know correct solution, Here is my code

```
    <?php
    function listFolderFiles($dir){
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($ffs as $ff){
            if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
                if(!is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                    echo '<li><a target="_blank" href="'.SITE_URL.'/'.ltrim($dir.'/'.$ff,'./').'">'.$ff.'</a>';
                } else {
                    echo '<li>'.$ff;

                }
                if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                    echo '</li>';
                }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    ?>

//HTML Code 
<div id="jstree-ajax"><?php listFolderFiles('../uploads'); ?></div>

//Javascript/JQuery code
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#jstree-ajax").jstree({
            core: {
                themes: {
                    responsive: !1
                },
                check_callback: !0,
            },
            types: {
                "default": {
                    icon: "fa fa-folder text-warning fa-lg"
                },
                file: {
                    icon: "fa fa-file text-info fa-lg"
                }
            },
            plugins: ["contextmenu", "dnd", "state", "types"]
        })
        });
    </script>
```

Here i have attached file pls check and let me know the correct solution thanks  [image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrap *file* string in quotes. As on [jsTree demo](https://www.jstree.com/demo/)

```
"file": {
   icon: "fa fa-file text-info fa-lg"
}
```

Also other strings in json should be wraped in qotes